# Only first hyperlink is selected in Range

Tags: vba, set, range

I have a sub where Range("A2:A4") contains 3 hyperlinks I want to open in webbrowser. By it opens the same hyperlink 3 times, while all 3 hyperlinks are different. Any ideas? Here is the sub:

```
Sub Hyperlink_Follow()
Dim c As Range
Set c = Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A4")
For Each Cell In c
On Error Resume Next
c.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
Next
End Sub
```

But this sub works and opens 3 different hyperlinks:

```
  Sub Hyperlink_Follow2()
    Dim c As Range  
    For Each c In Range("A2:A4").Cells
    On Error Resume Next
    c.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
    Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`For Each Cell In c`

Here `Cell` is the range variable that changes whithin the loop, `c` is the fixed range, so:

```
For Each Cell In c
   cell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow ...
```